# Powershell Script, send email (via Outlook) to user of script without knowing email address

Tags: powershell, email, outlook

My goal is to send an email containing log information to the person who ran the script.
Right now using

```
$Mail.To = "firstname.lastname@gmail.com"
```

I can manually type in the name of the user who I think should get the information. But I just want to know if there is a way for me to obtain the email address in some automatic way. I know that the application automatically sends the email from the logged in user. Could I use that same feature to my benefit?

This email is sent out using :

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
...
...
$Mail.Send()
```

Comment: Am I missing something our could just simply create a task instead of trying making the user sending a mail to themselves?

Comment: How about:
`([ADSISearcher] "(userPrincipalName=$(whoami /upn))").FindOne().Properties["mail"][0]`
(presuming, of course, that the user's AD `mail` attribute contains their email address)

Answer (score 0):

In the Outlook object model you can find the [Account.SmtpAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.account.smtpaddress?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm743);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) property which returns a string representing the Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) address for the `Account`. The purpose of `SmtpAddress` and `Account.UserName` is to provide an account-based context to determine identity.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I am having trouble understanding how to properly use the syntax you provided. I have the Outlook object labeled as $Outlook variable.